# how to serialize several objects in one file in C# with protobuf

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers

I have the class `Person`, and I want to have several instances of it, and I want to serialize these in one file. How can I do it?
I mustn't create a list of `Person` then serialize this.
I want can to deserialize one instance of class that save (for example fourth instance that saved). how can I do it?

Person Class :

```
[ProtoContract]
class Person
{
    public Person()
    { }
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int a;
    public Person(int d)
    {
        a = d;
    }
}
```

method to serialize:

```
public void serialize()
    { 
        Person p1 = new Person(1);
        Person p2 = new Person(2);
        Person p3 = new Person(3);
        Person p4 = new Person(4);
        Person p5 = new Person(5);
        FileStream file = File.Create("person.bin") ;
        Serializer.Serialize(file, p1);
        Serializer.Serialize(file, p2);
        Serializer.Serialize(file, p3);
        Serializer.Serialize(file, p4);
        Serializer.Serialize(file, p5);
        file.Close();
    }
```

method to deserialze :

```
public void deserialize()
    {
        Person nP1, nP2,nP3,nP4,nP5;
        FileStream file = File.OpenRead("person.bin");
        nP1 = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(file);
        nP2 = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(file);
        nP3 = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(file);
        nP4 = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(file);
        nP5 = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(file);
        file.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "protocol buffers" format is not terminated (this is by Google's design, so that messages can be merged by concatenation). The side-effect of this is that if you simply serialize multiple times, deserializing treats it all as one message. Fortunately, protobuf-net makes it easy to do what you want:

```
Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(file, p1, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(file, p2, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
// etc
```

and:

```
nP1 = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Person>(file,PrefixStyle.Base128,1);
nP2 = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Person>(file,PrefixStyle.Base128,1);
// etc
```

An alternative approach is to create a *wrapper object* - a `PersonWrapper` or `People` or whatever you want to call it - that *encapsulates* everything you want to serialize. This could be as a `List<Person>`, or as individual properties `Person0`, `Person1` etc.

```
var wrapper = new PersonWrapper { ... };
Serializer.Serialize(file, wrapper);
//...
var wrapper = Serializer.Deserialize<PersonWrapper>(file);
```

Finally, you could just serialize a list:

```
List<Person> people = ...
Serializer.Serialize(file, people);
...
var people = Serializer.Deserializer<List<Perosn>>(file);
```

Comment: tanks!
but I mustn't create list<Person>. because in main project size of list  is very big ( 100,000,000 ) and if I want deserialize all member of list take time.

Comment: can I walk fast among file without deserialize?